# '**' is not a registered namespace

Tags: python, django

I am getting this error only in this specific app in django i am not getting why

> root url.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url , include
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^login/',include("Login_Register.urls")),
    url(r'^PO/',include("ProgrammeOfficer.urls")),

]
```

> ProgrammeOfficer.urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url , include
    from . import views
    from Events import urls
    app_name = "Programme_Officer"
    urlpatterns=[
        url(r'^$', view=views.index , name="index"),
        url(r'^logout/$', view=views.logout, name="logout"),
        url(r'^events/', include('Events.urls')),
    ]
```

> Events.urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url , include
from . import views

app_name = "NS_Events"

urlpatterns=[
    url(r'^$',view=views.index,name='index'),
    url(r'bloodDonation/',view=views.bloodDonation , name='bloodDonation'),
]
```

the form which is triggering error of **'NS_Events' is not a registered namespace**

> template.html

```
<form action="{% url 'NS_Events:index' %}" method="post">
```

when i replace **action="{% url 'Programme_Officer:index' %}"** it totally works. I simply done nesting of url files . Why is this such error?

Comment: show us your import/include statements in your master url file

Comment: "You can't namespace your root url because there can be only one root url.Namesapcing is done only when multiple app exists.". Source: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39933269/django-root-project-url-namespace-not-working . I think is the same problem, right? Your *1st url.py* is root url.py.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django root project url namespace not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39933269/django-root-project-url-namespace-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

Everytime the new url pattern has to match . It must be in root url.py where the settings.py lies.
so in root.py include that pattern **url(r'^PO/events',include(Events.urls))**

> root.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url , include
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^login/',include("Login_Register.urls")),
    url(r'^PO/',include("ProgrammeOfficer.urls")),
    url(r'^PO/events/', include('Events.urls')),

]
```

**don't add it in another namespace**
and remove that pattern from ProgrammeOfficer.urls.py
i think nesting of namespaces are not allowed in django